# Tailwind Netlify - local site looks different from deploy

Tags: tailwind-css, netlify

I have a very basic setup, nothing special, just HTML (no Vue etc). I have Tailwind installed and everything is running. When I deploy to Netlify, Tailwind styles are applied, but still the site looks very different. I don't purge and I use the "netlify deploy" command.

**So here are my steps:**

1. I change something, watcher is running and outputting everything in /dist
2. I use scss
3. I run "netlify deploy" in my terminal

**Here are the screenshots:**

Local:

[image]

On Netlify:

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot more spacing between the icons and I wonder why that is. When I inspect the code, it's exactly the same. I have been at this for a couple of hours now and I can't procede before I know where this problem is coming from.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Added purging to the tailwind config, didn't help
2. Running "netlify deploy --prod", also didn't help
3. Clearing cache

**Sources:**

Repo: https://github.com/RobineSavert/map-portfolio

Netlify: https://6190119577337c9293c65f02--ecstatic-thompson-9cf61b.netlify.app/

**My deployment settings on Netlify**

[image]

*Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks so much!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the result to look alike first image, then coming to the wrapper for your icons on [line 30](https://github.com/RobineSavert/map-portfolio/blob/cbdf8e16437f97f7a13512dad5e6c6d566cc9162/dist/index.html#L30):

```html
<!-- from this -->
<div class="flex flex-wrap just m-16 py-3 justify-between">

<!-- to this -->
<div class="... justify-start">
```

would solve it, although i'm not sure about `just`??